# Kendo UI for Angular2 - Grid How to Add Columns Dynamically

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

For the Grid compomemet, if I already have a couple columns predefined in the html but the resultset can have a variety of additional columns on top of the predefined ones, how can I dynamically adds those columns?

There is no way to know what those extra columns are until after I retrieve the data? I am able to access the grid component after the data is fetched using the ViewChild directive, but looking over the grid's columns' array like object, I don't see a way to add columns programmatically on the fly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use ngFor to make a variable number of columns:

```
    <kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
      <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="columns" let-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="{{column}}"></kendo-grid-column>
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid>
```

If you want to try this out, see the "showing and hiding columns" demo in the docs (scroll down in the [columns examples](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/#columns)).

Comment: hello.., I can't replace 'kendoGridBinding' with 'data' please suggest me how to achieve it.

Comment: @shambhuyadav it is not necessary to replace your binding direvtive in order for this approach to work. The focus of the above example is to use the `ngFor` directive for creating the columns dynamically.

Comment: If you upgrade to the latest kendo angular ui, you can take advantage of auto-generated column https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/auto-generated/

Comment: how to use header/cell/footer templates for columns using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
 </kendo-grid>
```

You can directly add "gridData" without column names.