# How to dynamically add multiple kendo ui columns with the same field also customize the cell?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to use kendo-ui grid to create a matrix. The first column is the product title. From second column to the last column they are using the same field `productName`.

[image: image demo many columns]

The expected columns from the 2nd to the last one likes the image below. Which means there are many product names. The difficult thing is that I don't know how many columns so we have to add them dynamically. The [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606747/kendo-ui-for-angular2-grid-how-to-add-columns-dynamically) is for different fields rather than the same field.

Also the second hard question is that I have to customize the cells. In each cell I have to put a button and a text sitting side by side. I have a similar [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddocw5) for that. However it is for different fields also it is not dynamical.

Not sure how...